# sitemap for gatsby-starter-blog

Tags: sitemap, gatsby

currently i'm have issue with generating sitemap.xml for [gatsby-starter-blog](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-blog). http://localhost:8000/sitemap.xml still not found.

what i'm already doing :

- npm install gatsby-plugin-sitemap
- adding site meta

> ```
> siteMetadata: 
> {
>     siteUrl: 'http://www.localhost:8000',
>   },
> plugins: [ 
>   {
>     resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-sitemap',          
>   },
> ]
> ```

- here my code for gatsby-node.js

> ```
> const sm = require(`sitemap`)
>
>
> //const pages = edge.node.frontmatter.path
> function pagesToSitemap(pages) {
>   const urls = pages.map((p) => {
>     if (p.path !== undefined) {
>       return {
>         url: p.path,
>         changefreq: 'daily',
>         priority: 0.7
>       }
>     }
>   })
>   // remove undefined (template pages)
>   return urls.filter(u => u !== undefined)
> }
>
> function generateSiteMap(pages) {
>   const sitemap = sm.createSitemap({
>     hostname: 'http://localhost:8000',
>     cacheTime: '60000',
>     urls: pagesToSitemap(pages),
>   })  
>   fs.writeFileSync(
>     `${__dirname}/public/sitemap.xml`,
>     sitemap.toString()
>   )
> }
>
> exports.onPostBuild = ({pages, callback}) => {  
>   generateSiteMap(pages)
>   callback()
> }
> ```

Comment: The documentation here https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/creating-a-sitemap/ doesn't specify it is only for production/onPostBuild. I made a PR for documentation update here https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/pull/10857.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onPostBuild` is only called during the build process, not develop, which it looks like you haven't run yet. Try running `gatsby build` and your `onPostBuild` implementation will then be run.